# Mouseover & mouseout triggers event continuously?

Tags: html, jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I have a nest div that I want to hide on mouse over, and show on mouse out.

However, when I try to do that, the events get triggered continously.

The code is quite long so, for more detailed e.g.
Please check out the fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jWbZy/16/

Comment: Linking to an example of your problem is good, but you should state your question **here**, along with your html and jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

Add a wrapper around your carousel panel (i guess that's what cp stands for):

```
<div class="cpWrapper">
    <div class="cp">
        <div class="prev"></div>
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the folowing style:

```
.cpWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
```

And hide/show its child elements:

```
$('.slideshow .cpWrapper').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.cp').hide();
});
// ...
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kxvuk/

Comment: Thanks @Tatu! Though I'm giving @pinouchon cause he has lesser reps.

Comment: Don't look rep, check answer that suits you the best.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you hide the element, mouseout event fires also as the cursor is no more on the element. Instead, add the event to the parent element to get the desired effect:

```
$('.slideshow')
    .mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('.cp').hide();
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.cp').show();
    });
```